# Remove keyboard layout from OS X leaving custom layouts only

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have multiple nonstandard input sources that fully replace the original keyboard layout OS X ships with. However, the remove button is grayed out for the only original layout I would like to remove. It's obviously meant for preventing users from losing keyboard input if their custom layouts are not working.

Can I remove the layout manually from some config plist, leaving only the last three?

(In fact, it would suffice to remove the language from input select rotation.)

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Change the current input source to a custom keyboard layout.
2. Open `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist` (in 10.9) or `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.HIToolbox.*.plist` (in 10.8 and earlier). You can convert the plist to XML with `plutil -convert xml1`.
3. Remove the input source or input sources you want to disable from the `AppleEnabledInputSources` dictionary. If there is an `AppleDefaultAsciiInputSource` key, remove it.
4. Restart.

[image]

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44921/how-to-remove-or-disable-a-default-keyboard-layout for more information.

Answer (score 4):

This question was originally asked for *OS X Mavericks 10.9* or earlier, with Lri's solution being the accepted answer (as a side note, you can also open and edit .plist-files in Xcode without needing to convert them (maybe not back in 2014?)).

With *macOS High Sierra 10.13* till *macOS Monterey 12*, adding a custom layout and removing all other layouts from within System Settings was no problem.

However, with *macOS Sonoma 14* (possibly since *macOS Ventura 13*) it is an issue again, like thorstenhirsch said (sadly, I can neither upvote nor comment his answer yet).

Also his solution is working:

1. Lock the screen by using the Apply menu or hitting *Control-Command-Q*
2. On the lock screen, click on the keyboard icon in the upper right corner to select the (standard) layout you want to remove
3. Click the keyboard icon again to select `Remove Current Input Source`

Now in the list of input sources in the keyboard system settings, there's only the custom layout left.
There you could also re-add a standard layout and the button to remove it would be grayed out again.

Comment: how is this not the accepted answer??!?

Answer (score 1):

Can you remove the standard input source at the login or lock screen? That's what was working for me. The keyboard icon in the menu bar showed the standard input and allowed me to remove it.

Don't worry ending up with no layout - the custom layout is still there.

Comment: Note that this question may be specific to an older version of Mac OS than your answer may be for. Note also that this question was successfully answered several years ago.

Comment: The problem is reproducible with the latest macOS version (14.2.1 at the time of writing) and my solution is better than the one in the accepted answer.